# ember.js current date handlebar helper

Tags: datetime, ember.js, handlebarshelper

I installed moment locally with npm in ember v2.4.2. It works as tested in node session:

```
var moment = require('moment'); 
undefined  
var now = moment().format('D.M.Y');  
undefined     
now  
'18.3.2016'  
var now = moment().format('D.M.Y - H:mm:ss');  
undefined  
now  
'18.3.2016 - 18:11:51'
```

moment does not work in this helper `current-date.js`
There was just message 'build successful'  by server and no error messages shown in the browser even, just the blank window.

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import moment from 'moment';

export function currentDate() {
  return moment().format('D.M.Y');
}

export default Ember.Helper.helper(currentDate);
```

I'll give up using of moment and shall use the Date() function for current-date.js instead.
This works:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export function currentDate() {
return Date().toString();
}

export default Ember.Helper.helper(currentDate);
```

It returns date and time for my template with handlebar 
Date: `{{current-date}}` as follows:

```
Date: Fri Mar 18 2016 18:33:46 GMT+0200 (EET)
```

Comment: Used this exact same code for new helper and worked for me :o Have you used moment anywhere else, maybe its not added correctly?

Comment: No, this was first time. Tried just interactively in Node. In the beginning var moment = require('moment'); > var now = moment(); got this:  Thu Mar 17 2016 23:08:29 GMT+0200 (EET) or > now.format();
'2016-03-17T23:08:29+02:00' and > now.format('l');
'3/17/2016'
Can you pls show your code snippet of helper with moment() ?

Comment: I used the exact same code....

Comment: Are you relying on moment globally? Otherwise you'll need to import it I guess. `import moment from 'moment'`

Comment: Hi Kristjan, I installed moment locally and consequently tried `import moment` so as you suggested. How ever, I was not successful.

Answer (score 1):

Tried your code. It works fine. My current ember and node version are:

```
ember-cli: 2.9.1
node: 6.8.1
```

Try upgrading ur ember and it should work fine